# Rundeck Node Authentication with domain account

Tags: python, java, powershell, kerberos, rundeck

I have installed Rundeck 4.8.0 on Redhat 9.
I have a Windows 2022 Server node.
I have a local account on the node called rundeck and it’s in the Administrators group.
In Rundeck key storage, I made a password key, with the password for the local rundeck account.
In my project I have a yaml file pointing to the node with the rundeck username.
That works, I can run jobs that call powershell scripts on the node.

However, now I want to use a domain account, rundeck@MANAGEMENT.CORP

I have installed necessary apps:
yum install gcc python-devel krb5-devel krb5-workstation python-devel python3-devel

In My Project config, under Default Node Executor, I first tried to use the built in "WinRM Node Executor Python"

```
Interpreter - Python3
Authentication - Kerberos
username - rundeck@MANAGEMENT.CORP
Password - path to key store
Protocol - http
shell - powershell
krb5C Config file - /etc/krb5.conf
```

my /etc/krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    renew_lifetime = 7d
    forwardable = true
    rdns = false
    pkinit_anchors = FILE:/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    spake_preauth_groups = edwards25519
    dns_canonicalize_hostname = fallback
    qualify_shortname = ""
    default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
udp_preference_limit = 0
default_realm = MANAGEMENT.CORP

[realms]
  MANAGEMENT.CORP = {
     kdc = NYMGMTDC01.management.corp
     admin_server = NYMGMTDC01.management.corp
     default_domain = MANAGEMENT.CORP
}

[domain_realm]
  .management.corp = MANAGEMWNT.CORP
  management.corp = MANAGEMWNT.CORP
```

On the windows node the winrm config looks like this

```
winrm get winrm/config
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = true
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = false
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = true
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = false
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 2147483647
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 2147483647
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 1024
        MaxShellsPerUser = 2147483647
```

When I test I the node I get this error:

```
[ERROR  ]  generate_request_header(): authGSSClientStep() failed: (kerberos_.py:257)[winrm.vendor.requests_kerberos.kerberos_]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/winrm/vendor/requests_kerberos/kerberos_.py", line 245, in generate_request_header
    result = kerberos.authGSSClientStep(self.context[host],
kerberos.GSSError: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Server not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377))
[ERROR  ]  (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Server not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377)) (kerberos_.py:259)[winrm.vendor.requests_kerberos.kerberos_]
```

From my googling around, this points to a lack of SPN, but the node's SPNs look fine.

```
setspn -L NYMGMTRDNODE01
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=NYMGMTRDNODE01,OU=Servers1,OU=Servers,OU=Management,DC=management,DC=corp:
        WSMAN/NYMGMTRDNODE01.management.corp:5985
        TERMSRV/NYMGMTRDNODE01.management.corp
        WSMAN/NYMGMTRDNODE01.management.corp
        RestrictedKrbHost/NYMGMTRDNODE01.management.corp
        HOST/NYMGMTRDNODE01.management.corp
        TERMSRV/NYMGMTRDNODE01
        WSMAN/NYMGMTRDNODE01
        RestrictedKrbHost/NYMGMTRDNODE01
        HOST/NYMGMTRDNODE01
```

I even had our admin add "WSMAN/NYMGMTRDNODE01.management.corp:5985" incase the port wasnt being specified.
Also on the node itself I tested the winrm connection.

```
winrm identify -r:http://NYMGMTRDNODE01.management.corp:5985 -auth:kerberos -u:rundeck@MANAGEMENT.CORP -p:PASSWORD -encoding:utf-8

IdentifyResponse
    ProtocolVersion = http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd
    ProductVendor = Microsoft Corporation
    ProductVersion = OS: 10.0.20348 SP: 0.0 Stack: 3.0
    SecurityProfiles
        SecurityProfileName = http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman/secprofile/http/basic, http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman/secprofile/http/spnego-kerberos
```

So next I tried the Overthere WinRm plugin, rundeck-winrm-plugin-1.3.8.jar
I created a resources.xml  file :

```
<node name="NYMGMTRDNODE01"
description="Windows node"
tags="Windows"
hostname="NYMGMTRDNODE01.MANAGEMENT.CORP"
username="rundeck"
osFamily="Windows"
osName="Microsoft Windows Server 2022Standard"
osArch="amd64"
node-executor="overthere-winrm"
winrm-auth-type="kerberos"
winrm-protocol="http"
winrm-cmd="Powershell"
winrm-kerberos-debug="true"
winrm-domain="MANAGEMENT.CORP"
winrm-port="5985"
winrm-timeout="PT28800.000S"
winrm-connection-timeout="28800000"
connectionType="WINRM_NATIVE"
winrm-password-storage-path="keys/NYMGMTRDNODE01.password"/>
```

When I test this node, the debug shows this:

```
Debug is  true storeKey false useTicketCache false useKeyTab false doNotPrompt false ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is null refreshKrb5Config is true principal is null tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
Refreshing Kerberos configuration
        [Krb5LoginModule] user entered username: srv-rundeck@MANAGEMENT.CORP
principal is srv-rundeck@MANAGEMENT.CORP
Commit Succeeded
```

and then the error :

```
[overthere-winrm:NYMGMTRDNODE01.MANAGEMENT.CORP] failed: WinRM Error: Unexpected HTTP response on http://NYMGMTRDNODE01.MANAGEMENT.CORP:5985/wsman:   (401)
Failed: WinRMProtocolError: WinRM Error: Unexpected HTTP response on http://NYMGMTRDNODE01.MANAGEMENT.CORP:5985/wsman:   (401)
Execution failed: 106 in project Staging-Windows: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [NYMGMTRDNODE01: WinRMProtocolError: WinRM Error: Unexpected HTTP response on http://NYMGMTRDNODE01.MANAGEMENT.CORP:5985/wsman:   (401) + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, Node failures: {NYMGMTRDNODE01=[WinRMProtocolError: WinRM Error: Unexpected HTTP response on http://NYMGMTRDNODE01.MANAGEMENT.CORP:5985/wsman:   (401) + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={}, base=null)} ]}, status: failed]
```

I have found a lot of posts with the "Unexpected HTTP response (401)" issue.
I have tried to follow all the fixes, some people seem to have no resolution and some do.

I've on been this for 48 hours straight. So any ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks you.

Comment: "However, now I want to use a domain account, rundeck@MANAGEMENT.CORP".  Maybe I'm missing something.  But how do you expect it to work when the SPNs are linked to the computer account, rather than the domain user account?

Comment: John, you may not be missing something, I certainly am missing something. I do not know anything about SPNs and so I don't know about what account they are linked to. Do you know how I can rectify the issue and have SPNs registered to the correct account? Thanks very much.

Comment: Could you try with the "new"  Pywinrm plugin instead of the old and unsupported Overthere WinRM? Overthere WInRM is no longer maintained anymore, take a look at this: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-winrm-plugin#using-kerberos-authentication

Comment: Hmmm...this would be a whole project to troubleshoot.  There's could be any number of multiple things wrong in this case.  Not really sure how I can be of further help.

Comment: MagaDrive68k it seems winrm plugin is the one I have, rundeck-winrm-plugin-1.3.8.jar.

Comment: John you pointed at the SPNs, so I think the thing to do it remove them and re-add them correctly. I just don't know how.

Comment: Rundeck 4.8 includes the pywinrm plugin out of the box (py-winrm-plugin-2.1.0.zip). That's an upgraded Rundeck instance that includes the old overthere winrm plugin.

Comment: Ok.. so I was using the newer version first, where in the Rundeck gui I choose "WinRM Node Executor Python" as the default node executor. (I moved rundeck-winrm-plugin-1.3.8.jar out of the libtext folder and restarted the rundeck service). I'm back to the original error 'Server not found in Kerberos database'. So this is perhaps related to the SPNs not associated to the domain account. When I use the local computer account and basic auth, it works. So I'm back to how do I get the correct SPN ? Thanks

Comment: 'Server not found in Kerberos database' means you are using a wrong SPN.  Give me a few to look at this some more.

Comment: Have your admin run this then try it again:  setspn -S  HTTP/NYMGMTRDNODE01.MANAGEMENT.CORP:5985 rundeck

Comment: Ok I got my admin to add "setspn -A WSMAN/NYMGMTRDNODE01:5985 MANAGEMENT\srv-rundeck" .. and it works. thanks

Comment: I just turned my comment into an Answer, so this Question can be properly signposted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your admin run this then try it again:

```
setspn -S HTTP/NYMGMTRDNODE01.MANAGEMENT.CORP:5985 rundeck
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually John I misread you're answer.
What I did was:

```
setspn -A WSMAN/NYMGMTRDNODE01:5985 MANAGEMENT\srv-rundeck
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey, Roger try to comment this to John, instead that we he gets a notification tagging him.